# Writing a filename to a OutputStream when uploading to php server so the file will be named properly

Tags: php, android, file-upload

this should be real quick. Currently I have this code to write an image to an output stream and upload it to a server:

```
        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();

        BufferedInputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        int totalBytes = fis.available();

        for(int i = 0; i < totalBytes; i++) {
            os.write(fis.read());
        }
```

Etc. (I know that for loop for writing the data is super basic, I'm gonna make it a bit better in the future I'm just trying to get things working at a basic level here).

Anyways, as you can see I'm writing a file to the stream and sending it out, this works just fine. My problem is, I have no way as of yet to transmit the proper file name as well. On the php end I just set it to a generic timestamp file name, and I don't want to use the default image name on the phone either, the image uploaded will include the user's name who uploaded, including a timestamp which I can add on the php end just fine. I just need to know how to include something like a namevaluepair which has the user's name in it, so on the php side the filename can include that string. Thanks!

edit: dont know why i was saying data, its just an output stream...

Comment: How is your app sending the file (via post, other standard http protocol etc?), and how is the remote PHP script reading in the file (`$_FILE`, `sockets` server, etc)?  The protocols used might make all the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name is usually sent in the headers. For POST (which is usually what you are using when you obtain an output stream), you should have a content-type of multipart/form-data and each part will have a content-disposition header. For a part corresponding to the file (the only part, in your case), the content-disposition header should have a `filename="foo.txt"` component. The server then saves the contents in a temp file and hands your script the info contained in the content-disposition header (along with a means of getting to the uploaded file itself).

See [RFC 1867](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html) for details.